# PHP/MySQL code issue

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, database

**EDIT**
problem solved, used error reporting and found it was an issue regarding double quotes versus single quotes.

I am having an issue in getting this PHP/mySQL code to display anything. As is it simply displays a blank white page. I inserted a simple print command into different parts of the code and it would print that statement as long as it was outside of the:

```
} else {
    print "<p>Error: Couldn't find Confirmation code</p>";
    }

    if($updater){
    print "<p>Thank you" . $username . ", you have been confirmed and can now access our members page.</p>";

    }
```

section. That leads me to belive it is an issue in this area or with my if/else statements.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CS148 "Where Are You From?" Confirmation Page</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Stephen B. Wakita" />

        <meta name='description' content='Confirm Page for CS148 PHP Form Assignment.'/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php

    $dbh = mysql_connect('webdb.uvm.edu','swakita','password');

    if(!$dbh)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db('SWAKITA', $dbh);

    $confnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['confnum']);

    $tblname = mysql_real_escape_string('tblWhere');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tblname WHERE fldConfirm='$confnum'";
    $check = mysql_query($sql);

    if($check) {
        $count = mysql_num_rows($check);

        if($count == 1) {

            $rows = mysql_fetch_array($check);
            $username = $rows['pk_Username'];


            $sql2 = "UPDATE $tblname(fldAdminLevel)VALUES('4')";
            $updater = mysql_query($sql2);
        } else {
            print "<p>Error: Couldn't find Confirmation code</p>";
        }

        if($updater) {
            print "<p>Thank you" . $username . ", you have been confirmed and can now access our members page.</p>";
        }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting in PHP.ini.  Try adding some debug output to the if statement preceding the else statement to you noted to test if there is a logical error.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: are you certain the dB connection works?

Comment: Try setting error_reporting(E_ALL); in the beginning of your code and re-running - no white page of death with that option.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Ill see if I can solve this issue with the error reporting

Comment: Remove your edit part and place your own answer below, then mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaning toward

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE $tblname(fldAdminLevel)VALUES('4')";
$updater = mysql_query($sql2);
```

being the issue.

Please try this to see if you have any helpful feedback:

```
if($check) {
    $count = mysql_num_rows($check);

    if($count == 1) {

        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($check);
        $username = $rows['pk_Username'];


        $sql2 = "UPDATE $tblname(fldAdminLevel)VALUES('4')";
        $updater = mysql_query($sql2);
        if(mysql_errno()){
            echo mysql_error();
        }
    } else {
        print "<p>Error: Couldn't find Confirmation code</p>";
    }

    if($updater) {
        print "<p>Thank you" . $username . ", you have been confirmed and can now access our members page.</p>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Variable $check fail.";
}
```

Comment: Also, try to echo out your $sql2 copy / paste that into either phpmyadmin to test the query, or however you interact with your mysql server. Weed out any issues one by one. Depending on your error handling in php, it could be killing that function and preventing any response.